# ggplot2: geom_text() in geom_col() with POSIXt x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to figure out how to use the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518558/label-bar-plot-with-geom-text-in-ggplot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112587/re-alignment-of-numbers-on-the-individual-bars-with-ggplot2) when the x axis of the bar chart are POSIXt elements.

I want to plot a mean wind speed daily forecast and display the mean speed in each bar. I'm creating two plots, one with the daily means and another one separating night and day. The problem happens in the night and day plot, it seems geom_text() can't use the position_dodge() argument properly when the x axis is POSIXt.

```
require(lubridate)

data = seq.POSIXt(from=ymd_hm("2017-06-20 00:00"),to=ymd_hm("2017-06-29 00:00"),by=86400)

d_value=c(6.375, 5.875, 6.525, 6.200, 5.475, 4.075, 4.000, 6.200, 5.775, 6.425)
n_value=c(5.725, 5.700, 5.600, 5.750, 4.850, 3.750, 4.025, 7.225, 6.450, 6.100)
t_value=c(6.0500, 5.7875, 6.0625, 5.9750, 5.1625, 3.9125, 4.0125, 6.7125, 6.1125, 6.2625)

d_df = data.frame(data=data,value=d_value,key1="d",key2=1)
n_df = data.frame(data=data,value=n_value,key1="n",key2=1)
t_df = data.frame(data=data,value=t_value,key1="t",key2=2)

df = rbind(d_df,n_df,t_df)

ggplot(data=df)+
geom_col(aes(x=data,y=value,fill=key1), position="dodge",color="black")+
geom_text(aes(x=data,y=value+0.2,label=sprintf("%.1f",value)), vjust=2,col="black",position = position_dodge(width =0.9))+
facet_wrap(~key2,nrow=2)
```

The result:

[image]

**EDIT**: from: [How to set Bin Width With geom_bar stat="identity" in a time Series plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857875/how-to-set-bin-width-with-geom-bar-stat-identity-in-a-time-series-plot)

Actually, width = 0.9 means 0.9 seconds in the POSIXt axis. Setting position_dodge(width =86400) gives:

[image]

Comment: Do you wanna try first plotting them and then putting them into a grid instead of `facet_wrap`. That may help you.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I've tried group=key1 before and it didn't work either

Comment: Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857875/how-to-set-bin-width-with-geom-bar-stat-identity-in-a-time-series-plot

Comment: @Fallenlord is this resolved? If yes, please close as duplicate of your link?

Comment: @zx8754 That link looks like a work around to me. A better solution is still out there.

Comment: @zx8754 it is resolved. No problem closing it down.